# Is using mode 0664 in PHP mkdir a good idea?

Tags: php, security, permissions, file-permissions, mkdir

I am creating a website creation service where users can upload files in an FTP browser interface. I also want them to be able to create real directories, but I was worried that if they uploaded scripts, that hey could reek havoc on the server.

I am using PHP, and the `mkdir()` function. Would it be a good idea to use mode `0664` when making directories, to prevent:

1. Malicious files from being executed.
2. Prevent just anyone from writing or executing those files.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: I wonder if `644` on a directory _makes_ a difference. I've had php files with all sorts of permission setups on a cpanel server and they always run fine, and that is a 644 on the php files themselves!

Comment: @AaronGillion, well I guess that's my question! ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I would give it write permission to group.
It really depends on your server set up, on which user/group is accessing content when users browse content etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not make sense to use `0664` on directories.

You very likely need the X flag on them because you want to be able to get a directory listing. "Executing" a directory has nothing in common with executing a program. Disabling the X-flag on a directory will not affect execution of programs stored inside.

You have identify yourself which account is actually involved with file access. This account might be the owner of some files, and the owner of the directories of these files. Anything PHP does will be done as this user. So it does not matter if you restrict access to the file for the group or the world (aka `0700`). On the other hand, your FTP access might not be the same user, but only sharing a group. In this case it is an annoying idea to restrict this group to not having access to the files, because you cannot read, write or delete them.

If you allow users to use an upload facility to your server, and you cannot guarantee that these files will never be executed, you probably shouldn't offer this service. Using access flags will not improve the situation, because PHP does not need the X flag, it only needs the file to be readable. So if the FTP site should be of any use, being able to read the files is a must, otherwise why uploading them?

Note that the usual FTP upload/download service separates uploads from downloads. An upload is a one-way operation that places the file on the server but without being accessible. An administrator has to check the upload and move it into the download area where it is read-only. Nobody can trigger the execution of any file because the server will ignore any executable flags and simply send the bytes of such a file back.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot even open files in a directory without an `executable` permission. But you can access files in a directory without a `read` permission. A `read` permission is needed to **list** directory contents.

`0644` directories are inaccessible except by `root`.

## Examples

### Inaccessible:

`dir/` = `drw-rw-r-- (0644)` -- effectively the same as `d--------- (0000)`

So `file_get_contents ('dir/file.txt')` will always fail.

### Accessible, but no listing possible:

`dir/` = `d-wx-wx--x (0331)`

So `file_get_contents ('dir/file.txt')` will work if `dir/file.txt` exists. But `opendir ('dir')` will not.

### Fully accessible:

`dir/` = `drwxrwxr-x (0775)`

`file_get_contents ('dir/file.txt')` will work if `dir/file.txt` exists. And `opendir ('dir')` will return the contents of the directory.